# samsung laptop brightness issue? can,t change brightness on my laptop

Tags: laptop, samsung

I have installed windows 7 on my samsung laptop,but there is no effect of brightness when i press fn keys,brightness remains same.what can i do? i m very worried! please help me.

Comment: Can you clarify the questions? If the problem in Windows 7 make sure you installed the correct driver. Also this website is intended for Ubuntu users lol

Comment: This is a known bug on some laptops.  Not sure if yours is one but you can change it from the command line see this question: [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/149054/107450)

Comment: Every thing is well but brightness remains same, no effect of increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Is this question about ubuntu or windows?

Answer (score 2):

Read this thread that I have posted
[Cannot change brightness setting using function buttons or using the brightness control bar on HP laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332657/cannot-change-brightness-setting-using-function-buttons-or-using-the-brightness)

Here is the gist of it

*Test-*
Restart your system, and when you get to the grub menu, select your distribution (Ubuntu 13.04), dont press enter, but press e (to edit).

This would bring up your menu entry for editing.

Append to the line with starts with linux (and looks like linux /boot/linux3.9. ............ (at the end of this line, leave a space and add) `acpi_backlight=vendor`

so that it will look like
 **`linux   /boot/vmlinuz-310-x86_64 root=UUID=3161dd63-38c0-44bc-bc1e-34b692209b0b ro acpi_backlight=vendor`**

After this press F10 to boot.

Now try changing the brightness. It works for me.

Now we have to make it **permanent**

To do that we need to edit the Grub configuration file-

In a terminal type

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

This would open the Grub configuration file.
In this file we have to edit the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**to**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

After that save the file and run (type in the terminal)

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update the Grub configuration file.