# Xubuntu 13.10 Screen Brightness Fn Keys

Tags: 13.10, shortcut-keys, brightness, samsung, backlight

I have a *Samsung Series 9 NP900X3C*, which has a *Intel HD Graphics 4000 chip*. When I use the the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys for changing the brightness, it shows me a nice OSD and sets the value in

```
/sys/class/backlight/samsung/brightness
```

However, this doesn't do anything to the actual screen. Instead, I have to

```
echo $number >> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

How do I fix this keybinding?

The same goes for the keyboard illumination, I've found the place in `/sys/call/leds/` to set it, but the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key combination does diddley-squat.

Comment: I've checked with the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog, and the keys do bind to XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown. Guess I'll have to make my own workaround script if nobody has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`. I highly recommend you check out this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/332672/198090) for more details on testing this and then making it permanent. That answer was a solution for the same graphics card that you have.

Comment: Already had that flag set. Removing the additional `acpi_osi=Linux` , running update-grub and rebooting did nothing. I'm noticing in the XFCE "User" settings, the option "can use video devices" is deactivated. If I activate it, a reboot will turn it back off. Guess I'll need documentation on what that dialog actually sets.

Comment: Now, removing the keybinding I had for the X86MonBrightnessUp/Down keys and rebooting once more makes the keys pop up the same OSD as before, changing the wrong brightness which does nothing.