# How do I set brightness to a lower level in Lubuntu 12 (HP laptop)?

Tags: lubuntu, display, brightness, monitor

I tried everything I found online, but none of the methods I found worked. The buttons don't work, and there's no such thing as **Brightness** in **Monitor Settings**. I tried

```
xbacklight -set
```

but it didn't do anything. (Theoretically it should have worked, I have everything installed and it actually ran, but no effect was shown.) I also tried

```
xrandr --output VG1 --brightness
```

but it had some error.

My eyes are pleading for help :3

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Linux is a file. There is a device file to change the brightness.

Open terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T.

Execute this command: `cd /sys/class/backlight/` .
Under this directory you'll find a dir named acpi_video0, you might get it with different name.

[image]

CD to that directory. `cd acpi_video0` and open the file brightness using root user.

[image]

You can write a command or a keyboard shortcut that does the modification of the file for you. It's up to you how you want it!

Comment: Thank you very much!

I eventually tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/332657/cannot-change-brightness-setting-using-function-buttons-or-using-the-brightness and it worked :)